# Как отцентрировать страницу

Tags: html, css

Здраствуйте. Не могу понять как отцентрировать саму страницу в браузере (так как задана фиксированная ширина ), что бы при изменении масштаба она не слетала в левый угол, а была по центру. Думал при добавлении падингов тегу body все решиться, но при приближении/отдалении она слетает налево и дальше.

```css
   <style>
        body{
            padding-left: 120px;
        }
        img{
            width: 120px;
        }
        main{
            font-family: corbel;
           width: 1100px;
            color: #14931F;
        }
        h1{
            font-size: 64px;
          text-align: center;        
        }
        p{
            color: #646F75;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 18px;
            }
            button{
                font-size: 18px;
                display: block;
                background: #14931F;
                color: white;
                border: none;
                padding: 8px 23px 8px 23px;
                border-radius: 30px;
               margin: 30px   auto;
             }
             h2{
                font-size: 48px;
                text-align: center;
             }
             table{
               margin: auto;
               text-align: center;
               border-spacing: 30px;
               color: #646F75;
            }
                td{
              padding:25px;
              width: 190px;
              height: 40px;
              border-radius: 44px;
              background-color: #DFDBF5;
            }
            .baza{
                background-color: #DFDBF5; 
                width: 100%;
                height: 800px;    
            }
            .flex{
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                margin:90px auto;
            }
            .first,.two,.three{
                background: white;
                  width: 540px;
                  height: 600px;
                  text-align: center;
                  margin: 29px;
                  border-radius: 25px;
                
            }
            span{
                display: inline-block;
               margin-top:20px;
               font-size: 37px;
              font-weight: bolder;
            }
            ul{
                font-size: 18px;
                color: #646F75;
            }
          li{
             text-align: left;         
          }
```

```html
</head>
<body>
    <header><img src="/html-css-starter-materials/010/сайт dz/Логотип.png" alt="logo"></header>
    <main>  <section><h1>Отличное зрение
        <br>
         для всех!</h1>
         <p>Мы поможем Вам исправить и улучшить ваше зрение 
            <br>
            в краткий строк </p>
            <button>Начать</button>
            </section>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
             <h2>Услуги</h2>
             <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Проверка зрения</td>
                    <td>Детское отделение</td>
                    <td>Лазерная корекция зрения</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Лечение кератоконуса</td>
                    <td>Лазерное лечение заболеваний глаза</td>
                    <td>Лечение катаракты</td>
                </tr>
             </table>
            </main>
            <main >
                <main class="baza">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <h2 class="ceni">Цены</h2>
                    <div class="flex">
                    <div class="first">
                        <span>Диагностика</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Комплексный осмотр</li>
                            <li>Скрининг поражения глаз при диабете</li>
                            <li>Комплексный осмотр с дополнительным сервисом</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="two"></div>
                    <div class="three"></div>
                    </div>
                </main>
             
                <section>

            </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: main {margin: 0 auto;}

Comment: Элементарно, я и не подумал. Спасибо)